# Generating View Dynamically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, dynamically-generated

I got this screen that have some static and some dynamic views to be created.
I want infinity number of views to be created and i think dynamic is the way forward
[image]

Now all i need is to create the top column with image buttons , the edittext with clientname and the spinner with cash in the xml (this is the layout i have currently) now i want if a user clicks the cart icon the views with product name, quantity and price to be generated dynamically and then the bottom views are also generated via xml

like this

[image]

As you can see there're two row of product,quantity and price. Currently this is done via xml can someboy help out how can i generate and arrange the row with quantity and price and product name in between an existing xml layout like this?

NB: the main layout is relative layout and the layout that contains the row to be generated dynamically is this

```
                 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/laygroup0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/lvpaymode"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoproduct0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/strproductname"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/autoquantity0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_local_mall_black_24dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/strquantity"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/autoprice0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/strprice"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can inflate instances of the above layout and add it to the parent view like this: parent.addView(child);

Comment: and do that every time the button to add cart is clicked? Can you show an example or a link

Comment: Yes you will do that every time the add cart btn is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I can not give complete code bc I'm writing from my phone, but I can give you more pointers. 
Create the parent layout in xml in the main layout. It will be much  easyer if its a LinearLayout (any other layout it will be much harder to deal with, more care and more code). 
Then use findViewById to reference the parent it in java code: 
LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.layout....);
You will use the parent to add in it the child views.

Next set up a button with an onClick event hooked up. In the onClick event you will inflate the child layout: View child = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.childxml);

Next use TextView tv = child.findViewById(... to find all the views contained in it etc. Set up other button events here if you have buttons. 
At last you can add the child to the parent: parent.addView(child);

If the parent its a linear layout with the orientation set to vertical all the views will arrange nicely one below the other.
If you add many views you risk extending more than the phone's screen allows it and it will not be scrollable. You can overcome this by wrapping the parent linear layout with a ScrollView in xml. Now it will work nicely.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I need it to be just like that layout as you see the parent is indeed Linear Layout but since views will added I have used the linearlayout uptop to put those fixed imagebuttons (they should be visible all the time) and the bottom layer with Total is where the scrollview ends so everything in between is scrollable the repeating layout is LinearLayout with two children an autocomplete and a linearlayout with two other childs.

Comment: Yes you will have the top and bottom layout that will be fixed. In the middle it will be the parent container for the dinamically added childs.

Comment: let me try your approach

Comment: it does not work every time i click the add button it seems that the view just is created only once. What i need is somebody see the orders he already added

Comment: Well learning to describe what you want can help somebody in giving you the answer you are looking for. Too bad only now its clear what you want to achive. In that case you will want to use a listview.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. but the listview approach would be very complex to use

Comment: I decided to go for Listview and tadaaa why didn't I saw it before?